# Haskell: "read" function doesn't handle "+" for different types?

Tags: string, haskell

This one is ok, no problem

```
Prelude> read "8.2" + 3.4
11.6
```

But this one is not OK

```
Prelude> read "8.2"+"3.4"
<interactive>:69:11:
No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of ‘+’
In the expression: read "8.2" + "3.4"
In an equation for ‘it’: it = read "8.2" + "3.4"
```

And neither this one:

```
Prelude> read "8.2" + 34 
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Why? I tried:

```
read "8.2"::Float + 3.4 ::Float
```

Doesn't work either.

What is the input requirement of "read"? The first one string, the other one none-string, in order to do math?

Answer (score 5):

your assumption that read works on the rest of the line is wrong!

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

it takes only the string it is applied to and not everything succeeding it, try

```
(read "3.5") + (read "3.5") :: Float
```

Note the parenthesis, also I'd recommend taking a look at [Learn you a haskell for great good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) - a solid introduction to haskell.

- `read "8.2"+"3.4"` does not work because, you try to add a string (`"3.4"`) and the compiler tells you `+` expects left and right hand side to be equal so it looks for a plus-instance for `String` (a.k.a. `[Char]`) because that is what the right hand side of `+` is.
- `read "8.2" + 34` does not work because Haskell defaults to `Integer` for unspecified `Num` types (`34 :: Num a => a`), and so it tries to parse `"8.2"` as an integer and fails because integers don't have dots in them.
- the last one is almost right, you just have to add parens to make it work (see above)

Your headline includes also a wrong assumption:

the arguments of `+` have to have same type

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

the type signature says: something "Numeric" (thats something like an interface if you know java) can use the `+` function and first, second argument as well as the result are of the same type.

if you want to have conversion you have to make it manually/explicitly